# Load a subset of all custom commands in a nightwatch test suite

Tags: javascript, frontend, nightwatch.js, e2e-testing

Is it possible to load only a subset of all custom commands in a nightwatch test suite?

E.g:
Test suites/test files:

- component1Tests1.js
- component1Tests2.js
- component2Tests1.js
- component2Tests2.js

Custom commands:

- component1Commands.js
- component2Commands.js

Component1TestsX files/tests should see only component1Commands. The situation for Component2TestsX is analogical. This is needed because of the eventual naming collision of the commands.

Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, it is not possible, and looks more like a bad naming practice.

How would someone else know what does the `component1Commands.js` do?

What if `component1Commands.js` already do the same thing that `component2Commands.js` do?

You would be breaking the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), the main idea of the commands its to reuse the code for multiple tests. You should name it correctly. If its needed, its better to separate the whole tests into two differentes projects instead.

Comment: 10xs Frankusky! I am accepting your answer because I also believe that what I am asking is impossible. Still, I do not believe that the DRY principle would be broken. Furthermore, I solve my problem with using nodejs imports and exports vs the nightwatch commands. Probably, the same result could be achieved with nightwatch Page Objects.